# TypeScript wrong promise resolved inferred type using the returned value of a callback function

Tags: typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

Note that some parts of the code has to do with AmCharts but the question itself is perhaps more related to TypeScript itself.

Here is what the JS functions within AmCharts lib are doing:

```js
export function createDeferred(callback, scope) {
    var rest = [];
    for (var _i = 2; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        rest[_i - 2] = arguments[_i];
    }
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        registry.deferred.push({
            scope: scope,
            callback: callback,
            args: rest,
            resolve: resolve
        });
        if (registry.deferred.length == 1) {
            processNextDeferred();
        }
    });
}

function processNextDeferred() {
    var _a;
    var next = registry.deferred[0];
    if (next) {
        var sprite_2 = (_a = next.callback).call.apply(_a, __spread([next.scope], next.args));
        sprite_2.events.on("ready", function () {
            next.resolve(sprite_2);
            registry.deferred.shift();
            if (options.deferredDelay) {
                setTimeout(processNextDeferred, options.deferredDelay);
            }
            else {
                processNextDeferred();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but important part is where my callback function is executed and afterwards resolved:

how lib calls and resolves:

```js
var sprite_2 = (_a = next.callback).call.apply(_a, __spread([next.scope], next.args));
next.resolve(sprite_2);
```

the `next.callback` is following function coming from my side:

```js
export function createChartInstance<T extends am4charts.Chart>(
  chartId: string,
  chartType: new () => T
): T {
  const chart = am4core.create(chartId, chartType);

  return chart; // returns instance of specified chart, like XYChart
}

const x = await am4core.createDeferred(
  createChartInstance,
  chartId,
  am4charts.XYChart,
);
```

So, following the logic, the `x` should be also the `am4charts.XYChart` right? Because it was the return from the resolved Promise. But instead it's of type `am4core.Sprite`. Why? Even if the `createDeferred` declaration is:

```js
export declare function createDeferred(callback: (...args: Array<any>) => Sprite, scope?: any, ...rest: Array<any>): Promise<Sprite>;
```

the resolved is indeed of type of the chart, don't?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the last code snippet you provided is type declaration for `createDeferred` that you see in the library. It explicitly says that `createDeferred` returns `Promise<Sprite>` so that's why it is of type `Sprite`, isn't it? Implementation doesn't matter, you really shouldn't look at the JS code that you wrote in the beginning. Typescript ignores it completely and just looks at type declarations, if type declaration says it returns `Sprite`, typescript says it returns `Sprite` even if that's really not the case

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the `as` keyword.